# Does (latin) 'cor' count as a stem of the English word 'courage'?

Tags: morphology

Looking up the etymology of "courage" reveals that it comes from Old French *corage* which comes from Latin *coraticum*, which is the Latin word *cor* ("heart") + the noun-forming suffix *-aticum*.

In English morphology, would "cor" be considered a root/stem of "courage"?

Some English words have latin stems: eternal (etern), audience (audi), clarity (clari)

Would courage count as one even though it became part of English after already having its full form? English didn't inherit the stem "cor", and as far as I can see this stem isn't used anywhere else (except maybe "core" but it's unknown what this comes from), it inherited directly a word "courage".

Comment: English has plenty of other words that ultimately come from (or at least contain) Latin _cor, cordis_: _cordial_, _misericord_, _accord_, _concord_, _record_, _discord_, etc. But I would not consider a Latin word to be the morphological stem of any of those English words (including _courage_), for the simple reason that it’s Latin, not English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet do you think etern- counts as a stem in English?

Comment: As a stem, yes (since it’s found in _eternal/eternity/eterne/eternise_); possibly even as a root, though roots in English should ideally be wordable, and _etern-_ isn’t. But while _-age_ is a productive suffix and can be added to roots/stems to form words, the reverse is not necessarily true: you can’t always take it away and be left with an actual root or stem. _Courage_, _homage_ and _adage_ cannot be reduced to the ‘roots’ _*cour_, _*hom_ and _*ad_, all of which are meaningless. The root of _courage_ is just _courage_ itself, I’d say.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet etern- also comes from latin though, so why do you think it should be treated as a stem differently to cor- ?

Comment: The fact that it comes from Latin is irrelevant. _Etern-_ is the basis of several words which, **in English**, are formed by adding regular derivative affixes to a common element. _Cor-_ isn’t even part of _courage_ – you can’t add an affix to _cor-_ and get _courage_. It is part of the other words, but it’s the (Latin) oblique stem _cord-_ that’s found in those, so it makes more sense to say that the stem in those is _cord_ than _cor_. It’s also debatable whether it’s useful to say even that, since there’s no actual meaning to that stem – the ‘heart’ meaning is long gone.